# With SQL, how do I return a result that is context-aware of other results?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, rows

Since I couldn't think of a great way to phrase the question, I'll give some details that will hopefully explain what I mean...

I have a few tables: Stores, Deals, Products

A Deal is pricing info (sale + list prices) for a Product, at a Store (foreign keys for both these).

So, in my Select statement currently, I'm returning a list of Deals, including their sale + list prices. Now, what I would like to be doing is this:

Instead of returning the list price from a Deal's row for a result, I would like to return the LOWEST list price, for that PRODUCT regardless of STORE.

Example Deals

```
storeID, productID, salePrice, listPrice) -

1,     1,       $5,         $10
2,     1,       $5,         $20
```

So, for the data above, I'd like it to return $10 for the list price for both the Deals. Hope this makes sense, I can provide further details if needed.

Example of current SELECT (simplified) -

```
SELECT salePrice, listPrice, storeID, productID 
FROM deals 
NATURAL JOIN products 
NATURAL JOIN stores
```

I should clarify, I still need to get each deal separately.

Comment: Can you update with your current select statement please?

Comment: You have to use min(salePrice) and group by other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to aggregate the `deals` table:

```
select productid, min(listprice) as minlistprice
from deals d
group by productid;
```

To get this as the *list price* for both deals, just join this back to `deals`:

```
select d.storedID, d.productID, d.salePrice, minlistprice as ListPrice
from deals d join
     (select productID, min(listprice) as minlistprice
      from deals d
      group by productID
     ) dmin
     on d.productID = dmin.productID;
```

If you need additional information, you can, of course, join in the `stores` or `products` table.

Comment: This solves the initial question, but I actually ran into another issue with it. The original results are paged (large number of deals).

So, I sort of run into a catch-22 with it, because the inner sub-select would need the context of the outer result to prevent selecting the whole set. If that makes sense...